# Как написать свою ОС и сделать загрузочную флешку с ней?

Tags: ассемблер, ос

Меня не интересует grub, меня не интересует код на Си или любом другом языке, кроме ассемблера.

Меня интересует, как написать код, даже не ОС, просто код на ассемблере, которые выводит строку на экран.

Я знаком с ассемблером, я знаком с тем, как работает загрузка операционной системы, я знаю про "магические" 511ый и 512ый байты загрузочного устройства, но я не понимаю, какой пакет ассемблера использовать, какие директивы указывать, с какими флагами компилировать, а главное - как полученный результат записать на флешку так, чтобы флешка стала загрузочной?

Comment: А это зависит от используемого вами ассемблера и линкера. И вообще от ОС под которой работаете. Можете поискать для вашего компилятора что нибудь вроде "сборка bin образа", не забудьте еще org 7c00h, потому что загрузчик будет в ОЗУ по этому адресу. А писать под linux например просто `dd if=файл of=/dev/ваша-флешка`, под винду конечно утилиты разные есть. Если что гугл по фразе "пишем загрузчик ос на ассемблере" дает много полезных статей, в том числе и по компиляции/сборке/записи

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за ответ, но мне интересно так же, как самому что то записывать на флешку не по правилам файловой системы, а так, как мне захочется. Захочел - написал в первый байт флшеки, захотел - написал в последний.

Comment: Записывать откуда ? В каком режиме находиться процессор ? Под чем в это время выполняется ваша программа ? Если программа записи под ОС, выполняющейся в защищенном режиме (все современные ОС), то это делается исключительно по правилам ОС, с помощью их функций, потому как ОС не даст вам прав использовать устройства на прямую. Если же вы вдруг под чистым старым BIOS (в реальном режиме) или DOS, то вы можете использовать прерывание int 13h (ну или напрямую работать с контроллером устройства хранения)

Comment: @Mike, в целом, первая причина того, почему мне нужно это сделать - это именно ограничения ОС. Ощущение чего то нечистого. Постоянно требуют использовать уже кем то написанный код, а это удручает. Поэтому я хочу писать что то полностью свое, чтобы использовать все возможности ассемблера, а не "У нас прерывания запрещены, извините за не удобства, воспользуйтесь готовыми функциями"

Comment: А иначе в современном мире нельзя, потому что если позволить программам работать напрямую с железом то получим времена DOS, когда каждый день рождалась сотня другая новых вирусов, которые при этом старались удалить все файлы или выжечь видеокарту/монитор или еще что нибудь. Современные ОС заботятся о том, что бы проверить права доступа программы и не позволить ей влиять на другие программы и делать что нибудь вредное для системы в целом.

Comment: Кроме того, посмотрите сколько драйверов скажем в ядре Linux для разных устройств хранения. Правильно - сотни (если не тысячи). Что бы ваша программа могла что то записать на произвольное устройство на уровне железа, т.е. средствами ассемблера без использования функций ОС, то вам потребуется писать сотни вариантов своего кода, чуть ли ни для каждого устройства, ибо их железные интерфейсы все отличаются ! Берете datasheet на каждую отдельную микросхему, каждого производителя и по нему пишите что то свое ... Это при условии, что производитель документирует это, а не дает готовые драйвера

Comment: Но если все таки очень хочется - то можете писать модуль ядра для своей ОС, он будет (скорее всего) в 0 кольце защиты и сможет работать с оборудованием напрямую (правда придется именно напрямую, через порты ввода-вывода, потому как в защищенном режиме прерывания bios на подобии int 13h не работают)

Comment: А вот интересно, каким способом вы выводите строку на экран ?

Comment: @Mike, в том то и дело, что я пока - никаким. Пока ассембер изучал, использовал NASM и DosBox, строку 0x10 прерыванием выводил. Сейчас решил, что первым делом хочу понять, как после завершения программы завершить работу машины)

Comment: Понять и, соответсвенно, сделать. Записать на флешку такую программу, чтобы при загрузке с флешки устройство просто завершало работу.

Comment: Ну вот, я примерно так и думал. int 10h - это такая же функция, как и запись на диск например. только предоставляет ее bios реального режима. А так то ОС должна на прямую работать с видеопамятью. Что касается управлением питанием, то возможно до сих пор bios поддерживают функции ATX https://superuser.com/questions/1094409/how-do-i-auto-turn-off-a-dos-only-machine-using-software-the-pc-has-no-power-sw Но вообще все ОС защищенного режима делают это самостоятельно, а это значит, что сканируя шину PCI находят там ACPI интерфейс и через него уже управляют питанием

Comment: касательно выключения через ACPI https://stackoverflow.com/a/40002262/5669174 но конечно это надо гораздо глубже изучать что бы правильно управлять питанием

Comment: @Mike так и не получилось разобраться)